# Magento 2.4.2 Adminhtml grid error

Tags: admin, adminhtml, grid, magento2.4.2, di.xml

So I have a custom table and I want to create a grid in admin html to display all the records from my custom table.
I created new page using page factory.
I created listing.xml and di.xml as well but I am facing this error.
spinner keeps rotating and after that nothing happens.
[image]

[image]

Here is my code.
/app/code/VoltLighting/FriendsAndFamily/view/adminhtml/layout/rewards_friendsandfamily_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="rewards_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/app/code/VoltLighting/FriendsAndFamily/view/adminhtml/ui_component/rewards_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">rewards_listing.rewards_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings >
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Member</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
      <spinner>rewards_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>rewards_listing.rewards_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="rewards_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="rewards/friendsandfamily/index"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>VoltLighting_FriendsAndFamily::resource</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="rewards_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="rewards_columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="cms/block/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">rewards_listing.rewards_listing.rewards_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">rewards_listing.rewards_listing.rewards_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="purchase_date">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Purchase Date</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="amount">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Amount</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="customer_email">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Email</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>

        <column name="referrer_email">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Referrer Email</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="order_number">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Order Number</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="check_date">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Check Date</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>




    </columns>

</listing>
```

/app/code/VoltLighting/FriendsAndFamily/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="rewards_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">friends_and_family_rewards</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

/app/code/VoltLighting/FriendsAndFamily/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php


namespace VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Creating table trellis_customer
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('friends_and_family_rewards')
        )->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Entity Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'purchase_date',
            Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Purchase Date'
        )->addColumn(
            'amount',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'default' => null],
            'Amount'
        )->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'default' => null],
            'Customer ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'customer_email',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
            'Customer Email'
        )->addColumn(
            'referrer_email',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
            'Referrer Email'
        )->addColumn(
            'order_number',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
            'Order Number'
        )->addColumn(
            'check_date',
            Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
            1,
            ['nullable' => false,'default' => 0],
            'Check Date'
        )->setComment(
            'Friends And Family Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I feel the issue is in my listing.xml with the datasource but I am unable to understand where I am going wrong. If anyone can help I will really appreciate it.

```
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Documentation was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_HelpCenter was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Licenses was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::Modules_License was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Debugger was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Debugger_Rewrites was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Debugger_Modules was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::WeltPixel_Debugger_Developer was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_Backend::Pearl_Theme_Options was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Ulmod_AdvancedBreadcrumbs::umseo_advancedbreadcrumbs was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Ulmod_AdvancedBreadcrumbs::category was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id VoltLighting_FriendsAndFamily::rewards was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id VoltLighting_FriendsAndFamily::rewards_friendsfamily was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_GoogleTagManager::GoogleTagManager_Label was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id WeltPixel_GoogleTagManager::GoogleTagManager was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_XtCore::extensions was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::configuration was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::menu was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::manual was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::log was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::profile was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:22] report.INFO: Add of item with id Xtento_ProductExport::destination was processed [] []
[2021-06-04 18:30:31] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

exception.log

```
[2021-06-03 19:57:01] report.CRITICAL: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Transport.php:141, Laminas\\Mail\\Protocol\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:351)"} []
[2021-06-03 19:57:01] report.CRITICAL: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Transport.php:141, Laminas\\Mail\\Protocol\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/laminas/laminas-mail/src/Protocol/AbstractProtocol.php:351)"} []
[2021-06-03 20:10:38] report.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:94)"} []
[2021-06-03 20:10:38] report.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:94)"} []
[2021-06-03 20:10:38] report.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:94)"} []
[2021-06-03 20:10:38] report.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag omsordertaker invalid in Entity, line: 1 at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:94)"} []
[2021-06-04 15:45:48] report.CRITICAL: Class VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\Grid\Collection does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class VoltLighting\\FriendsAndFamily\\Model\\ResourceModel\\CustomerData\\Grid\\Collection does not exist at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24)"} []
[2021-06-04 15:45:48] report.CRITICAL: Class VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\Grid\Collection does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class VoltLighting\\FriendsAndFamily\\Model\\ResourceModel\\CustomerData\\Grid\\Collection does not exist at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24)"} []
[2021-06-04 18:54:27] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
[2021-06-04 18:54:27] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
[2021-06-04 19:07:33] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
[2021-06-04 19:07:33] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
[2021-06-04 19:10:52] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
[2021-06-04 19:10:52] report.CRITICAL: rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): rewards_listing_data_source is not of Collection type. at /Users/mkt21-maclap/Sites/localhost/voltlocal/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php:53)"} []
```

Comment: can you Please check error log

Comment: mamp apache error logs?

Comment: Please share your magento /var/log/ error

Comment: I have added my system.log error in my post

Comment: please one exception error log

Comment: I have added exception.log file

Answer (score 0):

I think that line is not correct:

```
<argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData</argument>
        </arguments>
```

Instead of `xsi:type="string"` try to change by `xsi:type="object"`

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/app/code/VoltLighting/FriendsAndFamily/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"">
    <virtualType name=""AccountGridFilterPool"" type=""Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool"">
        <arguments>
            <argument name=""appliers"" xsi:type=""array"">
                <item name=""regular"" xsi:type=""object"">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name=""fulltext"" xsi:type=""object"">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name=""VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData\Grid\Collection"">
        <arguments>
            <argument name=""mainTable"" xsi:type=""string"">magenest_rewardpoints_account</argument>
            <argument name=""resourceModel"" xsi:type=""string"">VoltLighting\FriendsAndFamily\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```